# Custom function to summarize dataframe based on variable class

Tags: r, dataframe, function, class

I am trying to write a custom function in R that takes the mean and standard deviation, if the variable is numeric; or counts the number of occurrences for each level, if the variable is categorical. As an additional twist, I would like the function to only count the number of "Yes" if the variable is categorical and its levels include "Yes". Ideally, I would like this to be an input parameter, which if called, only counts the number of "Yes".

To demonstrate, let's assume we have the following data:

```
Height <- round(rnorm(10, 175, 10), 0)
weight <- round(rnorm(10, 70, 10), 0)
smoke <- c(rep("Yes", 3), rep("No", 4), rep("Unknown", 3))
problem <- c(rep("depression", 3), rep("insomnia", 2), rep("IBS", 5))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Height, weight, smoke, problem))

data$Height <- as.numeric(data$Height)
data$weight <- as.numeric(data$weight)
data$smoke <- factor(data$smoke, levels = c("Yes", "No", "Unknown"))
data$problem <- factor(data$problem, levels = c("depression", "insomnia", "IBS"))
```

The function I have is:

```
sumfun <- function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)){
    m = round(mean(x, na.rm = T), digits = 2)
    s = round(sd(x, na.rm = T), digits = 2)
    return(list(cbind("", paste0(m, " ", "(", s, ")", " ", "/", " ", sum(!is.na(x))))))
  } else
    # (is.factor(x) | is.character(x)){
    n = table(x)
  pro = round(prop.table(n), 2)
  return(list(cbind("", levels(x), paste0(n, " ", "(", pro*100, ")", " ", "/", sum(!is.na(x))))))
}
```

Because I want the output to be in a specific way, I wrote another function instead of using apply family. This function is:

```
tabsum <- function(table){
out <- data.frame()
  for(col in colnames(table)){
    # out <- rbind(out, list(col, "", ""))
    out[nrow(out) + 1, 1] <- col
    for(row in sumfun(table[, col])){
      if(is.numeric(table[,col])){
        out[nrow(out), 2:3] <- row
      } else {
        out[nrow(out), 2:3] <- c("", "")
        out <- rbind(out, as.data.frame(row))  
      }
    }
  }  
  colnames(out) <- c("Variable", "Levels", "Mean (SD) or N (%)")
  return(out)
}
```

Using these two function on the data set above produces:

`tabsum(data)`

| Variable | Levels | Mean (SD) or N (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Height |  | 174.5 (8) / 10 |
| weight |  | 71.7 (8.68) / 10 |
| smoke |  |  |
|  | Yes | 3 (30) /10 |
|  | No | 4 (40) /10 |
|  | Unknown | 3 (30) /10 |
| problem |  |  |
|  | depression | 3 (30) /10 |
|  | insomnia | 2 (20) /10 |
|  | IBS | 5 (50) /10 |

What I would like to happen is:

`tabsum(sumfun(data, "smoke"))`

| Variable | Levels | Mean (SD) or N (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Height |  | 174.5 (8) / 10 |
| weight |  | 71.7 (8.68) / 10 |
| smoke |  |  |
|  | Yes | 3 (30) /10 |
| problem |  |  |
|  | depression | 3 (30) /10 |
|  | insomnia | 2 (20) /10 |
|  | IBS | 5 (50) /10 |

Any ideas are highly appreciated. Kindly note that there may be less painful ways to do this, but I am learning how to write R functions and would like to do it via a custom function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code updated to only include factor level 'Yes' for the factor fields:

For the `sumfun` function:

- I dropped the `else` statement altogether
- I added another `if` statement because factor inclusion is conditional to containing a factor level "Yes"

  - Within this `if` statement, you used the function `table`. You used `table` as an object name in `tabsum`: I encourage you to use a different object name, so there is no confusion.
  - I modified the call to `table` to be conditional and remove empty levels.
  - I changed the return list quite a bit.

```
sumfun <- function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)){
    m = round(mean(x, na.rm = T), digits = 2)
    s = round(sd(x, na.rm = T), digits = 2)
    return(list(cbind("", paste0(m, " ", "(", s, ")", " ", "/", " ", sum(!is.na(x))))))
  } 
  if(is.factor(x)){
    if(length(x[x == "Yes"]) > 0){
      n = table(droplevels(x[x == "Yes"]))
      return(list(cbind("", "Yes", paste0(n, " ", 
                                          "(" , n/sum(!is.na(x)) * 100, ")", 
                                          " ", "/ ", sum(!is.na(x))))))
    }
  }
}
```

In the `tabsum` function:

- I removed `out[nrow(out) + 1, 1] <- col`, otherwise every column will be in the table. Column inclusion is conditional.
- I added `out[nrow(out) + 1, 1] <- col` within the row loop, so that only names that return values from `sumfun` are included.
- I changed the `else` statement to an `if` statement with conditions.

```
tabsum <- function(table){
  out <- data.frame()
  for(col in colnames(table)){
    for(row in sumfun(table[, col])){
      out[nrow(out) + 1, 1] <- col # moved this in row loop, col conditions**
      if(is.numeric(table[,col])){
        out[nrow(out), 2:3] <- row
      }
      if(is.factor(table[,col])){
        out[nrow(out), 2:3] <- c("", "")
        out <- rbind(out, as.data.frame(row)) 
      }
    }
  }
  colnames(out) <- c("Variable", "Levels", "Mean (SD) or N (%)")
  return(out)
}
tabsum(data)
#   Variable Levels Mean (SD) or N (%)
# 1   Height        174.2 (12.05) / 10
# 2   weight         71.3 (12.47) / 10
# 3    smoke                          
# 4             Yes        3 (30) / 10
```

Now that `smoke == 'Yes'` is all that's included, you could put the information in one row.

To do this, in `sumfun` change the final `return` call by dropping the initial `""`:

```
return(list(cbind("Yes", paste0(n, " ", 
                                "(" , n/sum(!is.na(x)) * 100, ")",      
                                " ", "/ ", sum(!is.na(x))))))
```

And in `tabsum`, change the `if(is.factor...` to only have one call to `out`, like so:

```
if(is.factor(table[,col])){
  out[nrow(out), 1:3] <- c(col, row)
}
```

This modifies the table to the following:

```
tabsum(data)
#   Variable Levels Mean (SD) or N (%)
# 1   Height        174.2 (12.05) / 10
# 2   weight         71.3 (12.47) / 10
# 3    smoke    Yes        3 (30) / 10
```